# Function doesn't show noting on click in button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, ionic-framework

Hy people,

Can you help me on may code in http://play.ionic.io/app/44e0a65d2252

I have a button thar calls a function with 2 parameters when i click on it its 
supposed to show a `<p>` tag with some data.

JS:

```
this.showTime = function(stopcode, linha){
      //alert("Selected Value: " + stopcode +" "+ linha);
      $http.get("http://188.251.238.127/?code="+ stopcode+"&lcode="+linha)
            .success(function (datastop){
                  self.smsbus = datastop.linhas;
                  DataStore.smsbus = self.smsbus;
            })
            .error(function(error){
                DataStore.smsbus.length = 0;
                alert("Endereço inválido.")
            });
    };
```

HTML:

```
<button class="button button-block button-energized" ng-click="homeCtl.showTime(stopcode, linha)">Procurar</button>

      <div>
        <p ng-repeat="smsbuss in homeCtl.smsbus">{{smsbuss.eta}}<p>
      </div>
```

Comment: [Data returned in the callback is going to be in the `data` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage) of the response object so it probably should be `datastop.data.linhas` if you are returning proper JSON.

Comment: I already try your sugestion and doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @user3332475 you should declare an **global variable** so that it will work since it is an local variable it is not showing